# Combinatorial interpretation of $\prod_{i\geq 1} (1-q^i)$ in terms of partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I know that the expression $\prod_{i\geq 1} (1+q^i)$ counts the number of partitions of of $n$ with distinct parts. I was wondering if we could have the same interpretation of the expression $\prod_{i\geq 1} (1-q^i)$, just disregarding the negative sign in the expression. If this is not the case, how could one interpret the second expression in terms of partitions?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the difference of the number of partitions with distinct parts having and even number of parts and those with and odd number of parts.

Try it out until $3$.

$(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3) = (1 -q -q^2 +q^3) - (q^3 -q^4 -q^5 +q^6)= 1-q -q^2 +q^4 +q^5-q^6$.

The terms up to order $3$ are thus as in the final product.

You see that there is no $q^3$. As you have $1+2$ and $3$ as partitions so the difference of even and odd is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

A typical non-constant term in the product has the form $(-1)^mq^{k_1}q^{k_2}\ldots q^{k_m}$ for distinct positive integers $k_1,\ldots,k_m$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is one such term for each partition $n=k_1+\ldots,k_m$ of $n$ into distinct parts; that term is $q^n$ if $m$ is even and $-q^n$ if $n$ is odd, so the net coefficient of $q^n$ in the product is $p_{DE}(n)-p_{DO}(n)$, where $p_{DE}(n)$ is the number of permutations of $n$ into distinct even parts, and $p_{DO}(n)$ is the number of permutations of $n$ into distinct odd parts.

Answer (score 0):

The [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) is $$\phi(q) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-q^k)$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{\phi(q)} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-q^k}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty q^{km}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n p(n)$$
where $$p(n) = \# \{ \sum_{i=1}^j m_i k_i=n, \ \ m_i,k_i \in \mathbb{N}^*, k_{i+1} > k_i\}$$
which is the common [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function).

---

Following the same lines : 
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+q^k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n p_2(n), \qquad \phi(q) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-q^k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n c(n)$$
where
$$p_2(n) = \# \{\sum_{i=1}^j k_i=n, \ \ k_i \in \mathbb{N}^*, k_{i+1} > k_i\}$$ $$ c(n) = \# \{\sum_{i=1}^{2j} k_i=n, \ \ k_i \in \mathbb{N}^*, k_{i+1} > k_i\} - \# \{\sum_{i=1}^{2j+1} k_i=n, \ \ k_i \in \mathbb{N}^*, k_{i+1} > k_i\}$$